# Сделать функцию и добавить её в меню, чтобы просто сохранить файл под тем же именем.(Python)

Tags: python

Сделать функцию и добавить её в меню, чтобы просто сохранить файл под тем же именем. Чтобы не появлялось окно выбора файлов. Как в других программах, когда нажимаешь Сохранить.

````
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Текстовый редактор')
root.geometry('800x900')
def open_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Выбор файла', filetypes=(('Текстовые документы (*.txt)', '*.txt'), ('Все файлы', '*.*')))
    if file_path:
        text_fild.delete('1.0', END)
        text_fild.insert('1.0', open(file_path, encoding='utf-8').read())
def chenge_theme(theme):
    text_fild['bg'] = view_colors[theme]['text_bg']
    text_fild['fg'] = view_colors[theme]['text_fg']
    text_fild['insertbackground'] = view_colors[theme]['cursor']
    text_fild['selectbackground'] = view_colors[theme]['select_bg']
def save_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(('Текстовые документы (*.txt)', '*.txt'), ('Все файлы', '*.*')))
    f = open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    text = text_fild.get('1.0', END)
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
def chenge_fonts(fontss):
    text_fild['font'] = fonts[fontss]['font']
main_menu = Menu(root)
file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label='Открыть', command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label='Сохранить', command=save_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
root.config(menu=file_menu)
view_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
view_menu_sub = Menu(view_menu, tearoff=0)
font_menu_sub = Menu(view_menu, tearoff=0)
view_menu_sub.add_command(label='Светлочерная', command=lambda: chenge_theme('light'))
view_menu_sub.add_command(label='Темнаязеленая', command=lambda: chenge_theme('dark'))
view_menu.add_cascade(label='Тема', menu=view_menu_sub)
font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Arial', command=lambda: chenge_fonts('Arial'))
font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Times New Roman', command=lambda: chenge_fonts('TNR'))
view_menu.add_cascade(label='Шрифт...', menu=font_menu_sub)
root.config(menu=view_menu)
view_colors = {'dark': {'text_bg': '#141613', 'text_fg': 'lime', 'cursor': 'brown', 'select_bg': '#1D917A'},
    'light': {'text_bg': 'white', 'text_fg': 'black', 'cursor': '#A5A2A2', 'select_bg': '#C7FCEC'}}
fonts = {'Arial': {'font':'Arial 14 bold'},
    'TNR': {'font': ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')}}
main_menu.add_cascade(label='Файл', menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label='Вид', menu=view_menu)
root.config(menu=main_menu)
f_text = Frame(root)
f_text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
text_fild = Text(f_text,bg='white',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10,wrap=WORD,insertbackground='brown',selectbackground='#8D917A',spacing3=10,width=30,font='Arial 14 bold')
text_fild.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
scroll = Scrollbar(f_text, command=text_fild.yview)
scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
text_fild.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте класс, например `Editor`. Добавьте в него все свои методы. Создайте конструктор:

```
def __init__(self):
     self.file_path = ""
```

Из метода `save_file()` удалите строчку в которой открываете диалог выбора директории.